# Can't push local git branch upstream

Tags: git

I'm working on 2 branches representing different features. Here are the steps I did.

1. Created branch feature_a from dev
2. Created branch feature_b from dev
3. Done working on feature_a; pushed to upstream and merged with dev
4. Rebased feature_b from dev to include all new commits from dev
5. Did some more commits to feature_b
6. `git push origin feature_b` throws: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.

I don't understand why local feature_b branch would be behind the upstream branch.
Note: I'm the only person working on this branch and the last person to commit to dev.

Comment: Have you previosly pushed `feature_b` or is there some label on the remote that has the same name?

Comment: When you rebase you create a divergence. You'll probably want to delete the remote and then push the local up.

Comment: @isherwood that was something I considered at first... I assume `push --force` would have the same result with less hassle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you rebased feature_b onto the latest changes from dev, you effectively changed the history of feature_b so now feature_b and origin/feature_b have diverged. You'll need to `git push origin feature_b --force` to get the change to origin.

The problem is that `git push` assumes that origin/feature_b can be fast-forwarded to your local branch. Since you rebased the local branch, the fast-forward is no longer possible.

With the `--force` option, you're telling the remote branch to ignore it's current state and overwrite it with your local branch. So `git push --force origin feature_b` simply overrides origin/feature_b with local feature_b.

Note that the `--force` option can cause the remote repository to lose commits, so use it with care.

Comment: That would make sense... Is this something I should do every time this happens or my workflow with using rebase is not right?

Comment: There's a wide range of thoughts on this, but in my opinion, rebasing feature branches locally and force pushing them back to origin is usually alright as long as you're the only one working on that branch. It can cause major headaches if other people are using that branch as well.